# SessionNotCreatedException while running iOS script using Appium

Tags: java, ios, session, appium

System Config with below versions -

Mac OS - 10.12
Xcode - 8.0
Appium - 1.5.3

Below is the script which trying to run:-

```
public class testclass {

    public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iphone 6" );
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "settings");
        driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL ("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Error As Exception -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=settings,
>   platformVersion=8.1, platformName=iOS, deviceName=iphone 6}], required
>   capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info:
>   host: 'INCDSZPC02604.local', ip: '3.209.248.73', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
>   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
>   Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
>     at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:82)    at
>   MobileDemo.testclass.main(testclass.java:22)

Comment: How do you launch an Appium node? Command and desired capabilities.

Comment: I run Appium interface and click on Launch button there.

Comment: But what parameters do you use there? You need to match parameters for specific device and OS!!

Comment: I use Platform - 8.1, Device iphone 6 but these are unchecked there. Am I need to check it and then launch the server ???

Comment: can you check is there any other appium is running background ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with changing port number of server to something else like 5555
and updating same in your code

```
driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL ("http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: Hi ,in appium server settings you can change the port.